# How to apply optional argument using jetpack compose navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, arguments, android-jetpack-compose

I have read: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args

That's my code:

```
    override fun getComposableSettings(): ComposableSettings {
        return ComposableSettings(
            route = "${BASE_ROUTE}?$ARG_SEARCH_TEXT_DEEPLINK={${ARG_SEARCH_TEXT_DEEPLINK}}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(ARG_SEARCH_TEXT_DEEPLINK) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = ""
                },
            )
        )
    }
```

That's my route:

```
    fun getRoute(searchText: String = ""): String {
        return "${BASE_ROUTE}?$ARG_SEARCH_TEXT_DEEPLINK={${searchText}}"
    }
```

It works, becuase my argument is always `String` with value: `{}`,
so it is not empty String but always have value, then I need to remove this brackets to make it work properly and operate with next actions.
For me it is nonsense.
It should be optional argument like if it is empty it goes with `empty defaultValue` and that's all.
In this documentation example string with value like `test1234` is added so it will work of course, because it is not optional argument, but rather it is forced to make any value.

Greetings

Comment: You can set `nullable = true` which will set the default value as null

Comment: but still I will have error like no path is found I've tried with nullable = true instead of defaultvalue

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code. It is working by not passing any value in arguments

```
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "profile") {
        composable("profile") { Profile(navController, null) }
        composable(
            "friendslist?userId={userId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") { nullable = true })
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            FriendsList(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("userId"))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Profile(navController: NavHostController, string: String?) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Profile: ")
    //Here the navigation to friendslist is not having any arguments
    navController.navigate("friendslist")

    //Here the navigation to friendslist with arguments
    navController.navigate("friendslist?userId=1234")
}

@Composable
fun FriendsList(navController: NavHostController, string: String?) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "FriendsList: $string")
}
```